# how can I use fs in react with electron?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I want use react+webpack+electron to build a desktop app.How can I inject `fs` module into react so that I can use it to read native files?
I have a component such as:

```
class Some extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.content}</div>
  }
}
export default Some;
```

in `entry.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Some from './src/some.jsx';

const data = "some content";
/*
 How can I read data by fs module?
 import fs from 'fs' doesn't work here
*/
render(
  <Some content={data} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I use webpack to build js codes into a bundle.js,and in index.html

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
...
```

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
...
plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$"))]
...
```

I find this config on the internet because if I don't add it the webpack will report error,but I don't know how this means.

And I have a very easy `main.js` which is the same as electron-quick-start's main.js

Do I lose some important things?

It can't be better if u can provide a existed example on github repo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use `window.require()` instead of `require()`.

```
const fs = window.require('fs');
```

Comment: this helped my solve the problem! Thank you very much! I has been 3 days stuck in this problem, i was even using webpack with only getting more errors instead of the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is probably to use [webpack-target-electron-renderer](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer), you can find examples of using it in [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **Don't lost time with webpack** with react and electron, react already have everything it need itself to pack themself when building.

As Hossein say in his answer:

```
const fs = window.require('fs');
```

that works for me.

Additionally on webpreferences on the main.js of electron i set this settings:

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  nodeIntegration: true,
  enableRemoteModule: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
  nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true
}
```

following the electron website that webpreferences are a security problem so we need to found a better a more safer ways as described [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content)

Comment: webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  nodeIntegration: true,
  enableRemoteModule: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
  nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true
} 
this one help me

Comment: `contextIsolation: false` together with `window.require` were necessary for it to work for me.

Comment: Configuring the webPreferences did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Since Electron 12 `contextIsolation` is `true` by default and it is recommended.

So with `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: true`

First see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation/

**FIRST** in `preload.js` expose the `require` function to renderer:

```
require: (callback) => window.require(callback)
```

**THEN** in `renderer` you can import it by:

```
const { myAPI } = window
const fs = myAPI.require('fs')
```