# Way to read filenames from directory and output to JSON with Electron & React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to make a music player application with Electron & React. I have been able to access music files in a resources/music folder when built and installed but I have to give the exact path to an mp3.

I have been trying ways to scan the directory and get all music file names to put in a JSON as the idea is the user could add their own music files to the music folder to be picked up by the app and displayed in a list.

Most solutions I see use **node fs** but I just can't get it to work. I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import Testpage from "./Test";
import song from '../Music/Taxi.mp3'
import FileSearch from "../filesearch";

const fileSearch = new FileSearch();

const dataPath =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? song
        : 'file:///resources/Music/Taxi.mp3';




class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fileSearch.search()
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div id="page">
                <h1>laceHolder Home</h1>
                <div>
                    <Testpage song={dataPath}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

```js
const testFolder = './';
const fs = require('fs');

export default class FileSearch {

    search = () => {
        fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
            files.forEach(file => {
                console.log(file);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `window.requires`? this seems relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428639/how-can-i-use-fs-in-react-with-electron

Comment: console.log() fs to see if it is actually getting imported.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, after hours of looking (im pretty new to react and electron),

I used the below instead of vanilla fs import and it worked!

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const electronFs = remote.require('fs');
const electronDialog = remote.dialog;
```

Thanks for your comments to look at window.require