# Electron app not preloading a js file (to read local fs from client)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to have a front-end React component (made by CRA about two weeks ago) in an Electron app read my local (Windows) filesystem so that I can search it (e.g. search for files with name 'waffles' in my Documents folder). In order to do this I'm trying to use `fs` on the client, like this:

fsMod.js:

```
const remote = window.require("electron").remote;
const electronFs = remote.require("fs");

export default async function (string) {
  if (string.length) {
    electronFs.readdir("./", (err, files) => {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        console.log(file);
      });
      return "found files!";
    });
  }
  return null;
}
```

electron/main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require("electron");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    // useContentSize: true,
    show: true,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    },
  });
  const startURL = isDev
    ? "http://localhost:3000/app"
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`;

  mainWindow.loadURL(startURL);

  mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    // mainWindow.show()
    mainWindow.setSize();
  });
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

electron/preload.js:

```
window.preloadWasRun = "---***PRELOADING"; // added to see if this was running at all; it's not visible
window.require = require;
```

However when my Electron app launches it tells me `cannot read property 'require' of undefined`. (Curiously, when I open this in Chrome, it tells me slightly differently that `window.require is not a function` instead). This tells me that `window` is not defined, and that the `preload.js` has not run.

If there's an easier way to read the local filesystem I'm also open to that; I suspect that doing it from the client side isn't quite right, and that the `main.js` file of electron might be able to do it instead; not sure how though.

Comment: what's window.require there is no window.require in electron, and why you assign require to window.require ?

Comment: @ash I found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762662/way-to-read-filenames-from-directory-and-output-to-json-with-electron-react

Comment: did you check this part const remote = window.require('electron').remote;

Comment: @ash not sure what you mean, but I did log out `window` before the `require('electron')` part and it didn't have a `.require` prop, so yes?